# how to increase tableView height with scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `tableView cell` at bottom that have view that I will see if I tap on this cell.
Then I do it I increase `contentSize` and then `scroll` to this `cell`. But I can not `scroll` to top on boot ton position. I happens like `tableView` have default size of `scrolling` and it can not be increased. My code

```
    if (indexPath.row == 29)
    {
        CGSize size = self.tableView.contentSize;
        size.height += 100;
        self.tableView.contentSize = size;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First in heightForRowAtIndexPath: increase the height of the that cell if the cell is tapped like:

```
if(cellIsSelected){
return height+100;
}else{return height;}}else{return height;}
```

and reload the tableview data.
scroll the tableview.